# Hibernate, Spring, Thymeleaf and Set vs List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I am learning Spring, Hibernate and Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf collections works with [Lists and Sets](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach) but certain relationships in Hibernate seem are better managed with Sets. This creates a issue when posting list data back to the server that is indexed like workgroup.people[0] etc

So if a Hibernate entity uses something like:

```
@Entity
public class Workgroup {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "workgroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<People> people = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

The question how do I get this into a useable entity in Thymeleaf?

Currently if I try to persist (POST) this workgroup entity with some people the form data that is sent back to server looks like:

```
workgroup.people[0].dueDate:18/09/2017
workgroup.people[0].status:New
workgroup.people[0].peopleText:abc123
workgroup.people[1].supervisor.id:3
workgroup.people[1].assignee.id:3
workgroup.people[1].dueDate:18/09/2017
workgroup.people[1].status:New
workgroup.people[1].peopleText:def456
workgroup.people[2].supervisor.id:4
workgroup.people[2].assignee.id:4
workgroup.people[2].dueDate:18/09/2017
workgroup.people[2].status:New
workgroup.people[2].peopleText:ghi789
```

And the controller:

```
@PostMapping("/peopleSubmit")
public String submitPlan(@Valid @ModelAttribute WorkgroupPeople workgroupPeople, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    workgroupService.updateWorkgroupPeople(workgroupPeople);
    return "redirect:dashboard";
}
```

Note I have a breakpoint on the controllers first line, but it never gets there before the exception is thrown.

```
Invalid property 'workgroup.people[0]' of bean class [com.exa.dto.WP]: Illegal attempt to get property 'people' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'workgroup.people[0]' of bean class [com.exa.dto.WP]: Cannot get element with index 0 from Set of size 0, accessed using property path 'people[0]'
```

Do I need to load the workgroup and people into a WorkgroupPeopleDTO object which stores People as a List? & then manage the relationship?

And why do people who use Hibernate seem to prefer sets (I understand the differences to list)

A concrete example would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Convert Set to List and then pass to thymeleaf page for listing them.
But thats not the reason why you get above error, doesnt matter whether you use Set or List, you should be able to pass them both.

Comment: "Thymeleaf collections only seems to work with Lists and HashMaps". That's not true at all, the whole question seems to be based on your misunderstanding.

Comment: Looks like the Set that you are passing has no elements,i.e. it is an empty set.

Comment: @RahulRaj whenever I try to send a List of objects like workgroup.people[0] to a Set I get the above error.

Comment: `whenever I try to send a List of objects like workgroup.people[0] to a Set `
-> Edit the above the post and add the code where you try to do this?

Comment: Include your `@GetMapping` too.  Try to add one element manually to your `Set` and see whether you get the same exception.